# Unable to use Multer middleware

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am working on nodejs application i which i have to implement the upload files to **AWS S3**. I am trying to implement the **multer** to parse the multipart/form-data following the article [here](https://ewiggin.gitbooks.io/expressjs-middleware/content/multer.html)

I am working on express 4

here is my server.ts code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({
    dest: './client2/content/images/uploads',
}))
```

It giving me error

**app.use() requires middleware functions**

[image]

**I want to access the uploaded files as req.files**

please guide me how to get the files so that i can upload it to **AWS S3**

Comment: is multer available in `node_modules` folder? if not, `npm i multer`

Comment: Yes i have install multer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This books seems to be obsolete, it's better to use the doc on the [npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/uploads' });

// single file upload
router.post('/upload', upload.single('test'), function (req, res, next) {
    var file = req.file;
    console.log(file);
});

// multiple files
router.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files 
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any 
})
```